# Features an ASP.NET application structure/code should never miss

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to know what features in app structure/code should never miss when we build MEDIUM SIZE ASP.NET web application. I.e.:

- Testing.
- Logging.
- Configuration file.
- CSS(theming).
- Master page.

and so on.

Could you please increase the list to see if we find a "never miss" list?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

That's probably not what you were talking about, but using a true MVC framework really changes the whole game and turns ASP.NET into a real, professional web development platform.